# What should be the correct interpretation of "office/construction/factory workers"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

office/factory/construction workers

Can I interpreted it as:—

Office worker-
**a person whose work is connected with the work of an office.**

Factory worker-
**a person whose work is connected with the work of a factory.**

construction worker-
**a person whose work is connected with  the work of construction .**

Comment: Workers in those three occupations. Please give more context.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: I suggest it's a racing certainty that anyone who used that disparate group of "workers" is just making a thoughtless slight at ***non-professional*** workers. They don't have anything else in common apart from being "wage slaves"

Answer (score 0):

The noun phrase "office/factory/construction workers" connotes a group of people who have in common the single known fact that they either work in an office, in a factory, or in the construction industry. We would expect that the next bit of writing would explain what it is that they have in common beyond their occupations.

Comment: Yes, I think what I said is same, Do you think my interpretation is correct?

Comment: Your versions are a very roundabout way of saying "work **in** an office' etc.